# How do people in Hell survive?

Tags: hell, afterlife

How do people in Hell survive it? In traditionalist circles, Hell is the full wrath of God, infinitely hot fire and brimstone, and extreme pain, suffering, torture, and it is called eternal death. Now since in traditionalist circles Hell is also physical torture, with actual fire, actual sulfer, physical pain etc, then I do not understand how a physical body can survive this. With a normal human body, if it is burned beyond recognition or tortured for just 50 years, the body... would be destroyed, and the person would probably be dead. If you add in that Hell is the full wrath of God, then if God was using 100% of his might to hurt the people in Hell, it is hard to see how anyone could survive that.

There is also all of the NDE's on Hell, which also show things that no one could survive.

According to the version of Chrsitianity which believes 1) hell is eternal conscious torment 2) Hell is literal fire and brimstone and 3) Hell is an infinite punishment, and thus infinite in intensity and duration, how do these traditionalist and literalist interpretations of the Bible explain how people aren't dead yet?

Note that although the *soul* is immortal and can't be killed, Hell in this view is physical with a physical body, and although the soul cannot be destroyed it is safe to assume that a physical body can be disintegrated, no matter if it is made of an extremely strong material like tungsten or titanium or Depleted Uranium.

Comment: This question has to be a matter of opinion. Jesus says 'their worm dieth not and the fire is not quenched ' Mark 9:44, but we are given no technical details nor could we understand such matters at present. The facts are made known in scripture. The question 'How' is not revealed in scripture nor can we comprehend such things now.

Comment: @Nigel J. The worm Jesus talks about is a quote from Isaiah 66. These are not corpse eating maggots. It is tola (תּוֹלָע), the crimson worm (coccus ilicis) whose life cycle imitates the crucifixion of Jesus. It is the worm from Psalm 22. If your worm/Jesus doesn't die, you have no eternal life.  You are dead.

Comment: What else are they going to do? Die? And then what?

Comment: @ארקדיוס Jesus said _their_ worm. Singular and possessive. It is an indestructible lifeform (worms are very hard to kill, even if torn in half or drowned) which, then, shall abide in unquenchable fire. His meaning, from his own context is abundantly clear.

Comment: People do not survive hell. They endure it.

Comment: @Nigel J Clearly you did not get my point. So be it.

Answer (score 2):

It is kind of a given that Heaven and Hell, even if they are actual places, are not part of our physical universe, and thus not subject to the same laws. After all, people in Heaven are not subject to the usual processes of aging and death.

In any case, God is perfectly capable of overriding physical law if he wishes.

Comment: So God can time travel and teleport?

Comment: Please use "Ask Question" to ask another question.